# Custom spinbox with "classic" spinbox display

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2, qspinbox

I need to use a double `spinbox` for my `QML view` and in this case, I based my `spinbox` on [this example](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html)  .

```
SpinBox {
    id: spinbox
    from: 0
    value: 110
    to: 100 * 100
    stepSize: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    property int decimals: 2
    property real realValue: value / 100

    validator: DoubleValidator {
        bottom: Math.min(spinbox.from, spinbox.to)
        top:  Math.max(spinbox.from, spinbox.to)
    }

    textFromValue: function(value, locale) {
        return Number(value / 100).toLocaleString(locale, 'f', spinbox.decimals)
    }

    valueFromText: function(text, locale) {
        return Number.fromLocaleString(locale, text) * 100
    }
}
```

It seems that when you use a custom spinbox, it is not displayed as a "classic" spinbox. It is displayed like this:

[image]

However, buttons are too big for my interface. I would like to know is there is a **easy way to display the spinbox as a "classic" spinbox** like this:

[image].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have no reservations on using the old `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` in your project...
You can use both `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` and `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` in the same file, by using prefixes.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as OldCtrl

ApplicationWindow {  // Unprefixed, therefor from the new QtQuick.Controls 2.0
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 400; height: 450

    OldCtrl.SpinBox {
        width: 100
        value: 20
        decimals: 2
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation for this [`SpinBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-spinbox.html)

If you want to use the `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`, then you can define custom Items for `up.indicator` and `down.indicator`

```
SpinBox {
    id: sb
    value: 20
    up.indicator: Rectangle {
        height: parent.height / 2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        implicitHeight: 40
        implicitWidth: 40 // Adjust width here
        color: sb.up.pressed ? "#e4e4e4" : "#f6f6f6"
        border.color: enabled ? "#21be2b" : "#bdbebf"
        Text {
            text: '+'
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
    down.indicator: Rectangle {
        height: parent.height / 2
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        implicitHeight: 40
        implicitWidth: 40 // Adjust width here
        color: sb.down.pressed ? "#e4e4e4" : "#f6f6f6"
        border.color: enabled ? "#21be2b" : "#bdbebf"
        Text {
            text: '-'
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thansk for your complete answer. I didn't realize that spinbox display was different with `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`. I might use it now but your solution is complete if I need to implement "new" arrows with  `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`. Thanks a lot