# With QtQuick.Controls 1.4, how to prevent focus change when mouse goes on ComboBox or SpinBox Item?

Tags: qt, focus, qml, qtquick2

I use a `ListView` and inside each `Item` of this `ListView`, I have a `ComboBox` or a `SpinBox`.

My problem is that when I want to `scroll` my `ListView`, if my `mouse` goes on a `ComboBox` or a `SpinBox`, **the `focus` will change and** **the `scroll` will now be on this `Item` instead of the list**.

**I would like that focus is set on these Item only if I click on them.**

Code example:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ListView {
    id: list
    ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
    ...
    model: DelegateModel {
        id:delegate
        model: myModel
        delegate : Rectangle {
             id: rect
             ...
             SpinBox {
                 id: spin 
                 ...
             }
        }     
    }
}
```

How could I proceed ?

Comment: Your `SpinBox` is of QtQuick.Controls 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: I use `import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with the old `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` components, that they greedily grab the mouse events. To my knowledge, there is no official way to prevent this.

[*Here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264705/2056452) you find a solution, on how to overlay a such a component (in this case a `Slider`) with a `MouseArea` that prevents that misbehaviour.

Alternatively you might switch to the new `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`-Spinbox. As this has a different default look, you might need to adjust it, to look (more) similar to the old one. [*Here*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43760203/2056452) you can find a description on how you can do this.

Remember that it is easy to have both: `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` and `QtQuick.Controls 2.x` in one file, by importing them with aliases.

Digging into the source of the `QtQuick.Controls 1.4` we can find also a hacky solution.

*Relevant Files:*

- http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/SpinBox.qml
- http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/Control.qml

We can see, a `SpinBox` is a `Control`. The `SpinBox` has a child `MouseArea`, which handles the `onWheel`-event. We're gonna disable this `MouseArea`. To access it, we need to know the index in the `SpinBox.children`. We see in `Control` that there are two `Loader` as children (Index 0 and 1). In `SpinBox` we have two other children before the `MouseArea` (Index 2 and 3) -> So we need to set `idOfSpinBox.children[4].enabled = false` to disable the wheel-sensitivity.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600

    ListView {
        model: 20
        width: 100
        height: 200
        delegate: SpinBox {
            Component.onCompleted: children[4].enabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

or if we want to have the scroll wheel enabled, when the `SpinBox` was clicked, we use:

```
delegate: SpinBox {
    id: spinBox
    Component.onCompleted: children[4].enabled = Qt.binding(function() { return spinBox.activeFocus } )
}
```

But then we need to find some way to lose this focus again.

Comment: Thanks for your complete answer. I tried both examples and they works fine.
However, at this time I need to use `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` because the `QML` part will be a part of a "classic" `QWidget` application and I need that some components have a "classic" look. It might change in the futur.

Comment: Added some other way, by inspecting the source of the `SpinBox` - I hope it helps.

Comment: Hello, thanks for digging into the sources, it works for SpinBox and it is a great solution. However, I tried to apply this solution for `ComboBox` but if you disable `MouseArea` ( `children[2]` ) , you will also disable `onClicked` so the ComboBox won't work work anymore